# Copy a file from build agent to App Service without using FTP

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

In my Azure DevOps release pipeline, I want to upload a file from the build agent to app service server. For security reason, FTP is disabled by my organization. Is there a way to achieve this without FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to deploy the file to the app service. In this task, set `Package or folder` argument to the folder path where the file exists.

Comment: Thank you Cece, with  Azure App Service Deploy task I was able to upload files in a folder on the build agent to "/home/wwwroot" folder on the app service server.

It seems there is no way to specify a destination folder other than "/home/wwwroot" .. I guess to chose a folder I have to use Kudu api?

Comment: Where do you want to copy the file to?

Comment: Hi Cece, for example under "etc" folder. It will be nice if there is a way to specify the dest path.

Comment: You may check `VirtualApplication` argument, you can specify the name of the Virtual application that has been configured in the Azure portal (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common). This option is not required for deployments to the website root.